# getting a button to sit with drop down menu

Tags: forms, button, nav

I'm doing a redesign for my class, and I can't get the button even with the drop down menu. I've been trying different ways but cant get them to line up.

http://jgoldd.github.io/wsp/Project/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this css:

```
button, input, select, textarea {
    font-size: 100%;
    margin: 0 0 0 10px;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    float: left;
}
```

and experiment it out! Good luck! :)

Comment: No. It's just the `float` that make this magic!:) If you want more explain go here: [CSS FLOAT](http://alistapart.com/article/css-floats-101)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using tables? Usually that solves everything.

Here's the working JSFIDDLE > http://jsfiddle.net/PV3p5/

And here's the HTML. Try it!

```
<table style="border:none;">
    <tr>
        <td>State:
            <select name="state_list" id="state_list">
                <option value="" selected="selected">Select a State</option> 
                <option value="AL">Alabama</option> 
                <option value="AK">Alaska</option> 
                <option value="AZ">Arizona</option> 
                <option value="AR">Arkansas</option> 
                <option value="CA">California</option> 
                <option value="CO">Colorado</option> 
                <option value="CT">Connecticut</option> 
                <option value="DE">Delaware</option> 
                <option value="DC">District Of Columbia</option> 
                <option value="FL">Florida</option> 
                <option value="GA">Georgia</option> 
                <option value="HI">Hawaii</option> 
                <option value="ID">Idaho</option> 
                <option value="IL">Illinois</option> 
                <option value="IN">Indiana</option> 
                <option value="IA">Iowa</option> 
                <option value="KS">Kansas</option> 
                <option value="KY">Kentucky</option> 
                <option value="LA">Louisiana</option> 
                <option value="ME">Maine</option> 
                <option value="MD">Maryland</option> 
                <option value="MA">Massachusetts</option> 
                <option value="MI">Michigan</option> 
                <option value="MN">Minnesota</option> 
                <option value="MS">Mississippi</option> 
                <option value="MO">Missouri</option> 
                <option value="MT">Montana</option> 
                <option value="NE">Nebraska</option> 
                <option value="NV">Nevada</option> 
                <option value="NH">New Hampshire</option> 
                <option value="NJ">New Jersey</option> 
                <option value="NM">New Mexico</option> 
                <option value="NY">New York</option> 
                <option value="NC">North Carolina</option> 
                <option value="ND">North Dakota</option> 
                <option value="OH">Ohio</option> 
                <option value="OK">Oklahoma</option> 
                <option value="OR">Oregon</option> 
                <option value="PA">Pennsylvania</option> 
                <option value="RI">Rhode Island</option> 
                <option value="SC">South Carolina</option> 
                <option value="SD">South Dakota</option> 
                <option value="TN">Tennessee</option> 
                <option value="TX">Texas</option> 
                <option value="UT">Utah</option> 
                <option value="VT">Vermont</option> 
                <option value="VA">Virginia</option> 
                <option value="WA">Washington</option> 
                <option value="WV">West Virginia</option> 
                <option value="WI">Wisconsin</option> 
                <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td style="padding-left:50px;"> City: 
            <select name="main_city_list" id="city_list">
                <option>albuquerque</option>
                <option>amarillo</option>
                <option>boulder</option>
                <option>central sd</option>
                <option>clovis-portales</option>
                <option>colorado springs</option>
                <option>denver</option>
                <option>eastern colorado</option>
                <option>farmington</option>
                <option>fort collins</option>
                <option>grand island</option>
                <option>high rockies</option>
                <option>lincoln</option>
                <option>logan</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```